# How to spy a class instantiated within beforeEach in Jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a class instance that should be cleared between each test, so I'm doing this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {}
  public bar() {
    return console.log("bar")
  }
}

describe('tests on class Foo', () => {
  let foo: Foo
  beforeEach(() => {
    foo = new Foo()
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  const spyOnBar = jest.spyOn(foo, "bar")

  test("should call bar", () => {
    foo.bar()
    expect(spyOnBar).toHaveBeenCalled()      
  })
})
```

but `spyOnBar` keeps giving me the error `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`.

there's a way to spy on method bar without declaring the spy inside each test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Order of execution of describe and test blocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks).

Let's see the order of the execution.

```
describe('tests on class Foo', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log('beforeEach');
  });

  console.log('describe');

  test('should call bar', () => {
    console.log('test');
  });
});
```

The logs:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/72035574/foo.test.ts (10.376 s)
  tests on class Foo
    ✓ should call bar (2 ms)

  console.log
    describe

      at Suite.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/72035574/foo.test.ts:16:11)

  console.log
    beforeEach

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/72035574/foo.test.ts:13:13)

  console.log
    test

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/72035574/foo.test.ts:20:13)
```

When you call `jest.spyOn(foo, 'bar')` method in `describe` block, the `foo` instance is not created yet. That's why you got the error.

**Option 1.**  Create the `foo` instance in the `describe` block and add spy on its method. Since all test cases share one `foo` instance and spy, we need to call `jest.clearAllMocks()` in `beforeEach` hook to clear the `mock.calls` and `mock.instances` properties so that each test case will use a clear spy object. The `toBeCalledTimes(1)` will work.

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {}
  public bar() {
    return console.log('bar');
  }
}

describe('tests on class Foo', () => {
  const foo = new Foo();
  const spyOnBar = jest.spyOn(foo, 'bar');
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('should call bar', () => {
    foo.bar();
    expect(spyOnBar).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('should call bar - 2', () => {
    foo.bar();
    expect(spyOnBar).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

**Option 2.**  Create `foo` and spy in `beforeEach` hook so that each test case will use a new one. There is no need to use `jest.clearAllMocks()`.

```
describe('tests on class Foo', () => {
  let spyOnBar: jest.SpyInstance;
  let foo: InstanceType<typeof Foo>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    foo = new Foo();
    spyOnBar = jest.spyOn(foo, 'bar');
  });

  test('should call bar', () => {
    foo.bar();
    expect(spyOnBar).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('should call bar - 2', () => {
    foo.bar();
    expect(spyOnBar).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you very much. The second approach is exactly what I need, but I couldn't find a way to infer the right type to `spyOnBar`. Using `typeof jest.spyOn` don't work as expected and `@jest/globals` doesn't seems to export the type `SpyInstance`, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @YagoBiermann I am not sure. My jest version is *26.x*, the `SpyInstance` interface is available.